# Using 'class="select-chosen"'

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-chosen

I'm looking to use select-chosen for my select dropdown as it has both a search feature and a flat UI which matches the UI of what I'm working on. (So trying to stay away from 'select2', 'chosen-select', etc.)

[image: Example screenshot]

[Link to example page](http://demo.pixelcave.com/proui/page_forms_components.php)

When I inspect the element in Chrome to see how it works I find:

```
<select id="example-chosen" name="example-chosen" class="select-chosen" style="width: 250px; display: none;">
```

I also find that it seems to depend on: 'bootstrap.min', 'main' and 'plugins' css/js all of which are imported into my project.

However when I try to put this into practice I get nothing. Disabling 'display:none' returns:

[image: display: none (disabled)]

I think I'm right in saying that the 'display: none' is there because bootstrap generates a new dropdown requiring me to 'hide' my hard-coded one. Surely then, the select-chosen is not being generated?

To clarify, I'm trying to recreate the dropdown shown in the example link on my own page.

Here is a snippet of the code I'm using:

```
<select name="user" id="user-select" class="select-chosen" style="display:none;"><option>admin</option><option>user</option></select>
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Which plugin are you using post the `url`

Comment: You have a missing quote here `name=example-chosen" `, it should be `name="example-chosen" `

Comment: Thanks for pointing out missing quote

Comment: What do you mean by: "Which plugin are you using post the url"?

Comment: I'm not sure what U are trying to achieve.

Comment: I've updated the question, hope that makes it more clear.

Comment: @Burtalmighty Have you tried remove attributes one by one? `display: none` may be causing select being skipped

Comment: I think that You are trying to achieve this without 3-rd party libraries, so You should style the <select> tag Yourself. Could You provide us a little fiddle ?

Comment: Yeah I've tried it with everything but the class removed, but that just returns the same result except I don't have to disable 'display: none' due to its lack of presence.

Comment: Can you show us your actual code please? My first guess is you aren't linking to the chosen.js javascript or using the correct selector to launch that js.

Comment: Quick JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kbo4uv4j/ unfortunately I can't import boiler plate main or plugins css/js so seems a pretty pointless fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/CBjmj/220/)**.

The example in your page use the jQuery plugin **[`chosen`](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)** and the css of bootstrap so it will be **[`bootstrap-chosen`](http://alxlit.name/bootstrap-chosen/)**, you have just to define your `select` as usual and add `chosen` class to it then init the plugin using `$('.chosen').chosen();`, check the example bellow.

**HTML :**

```
<select class="form-control chosen" data-placeholder="Choose an option please">                     
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1" >Option 1</option>
  <option value="2" >Option 2</option>
</select>
```

**JS :**

```
$('.chosen').chosen();
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('.chosen').chosen();
```

```css
select.form-control + .chosen-container.chosen-container-single .chosen-single {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: #555;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075);
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
  transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
  background-image:none;
}

select.form-control + .chosen-container.chosen-container-single .chosen-single div {
  top:4px;
  color:#000;
}

select.form-control + .chosen-container .chosen-drop {
  background-color: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  background-clip: padding-box;
  margin: 2px 0 0;

}

select.form-control + .chosen-container .chosen-search input[type=text] {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: #555;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
  transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
  background-image:none;
}

select.form-control + .chosen-container .chosen-results {
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  padding: 5px 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

select.form-control + .chosen-container .chosen-results li , 
select.form-control + .chosen-container .chosen-results li.active-result {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: #333;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-image:none;
}
select.form-control + .chosen-container .chosen-results li:hover, 
select.form-control + .chosen-container .chosen-results li.active-result:hover,
select.form-control + .chosen-container .chosen-results li.highlighted
{
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #428BCA;
  background-image:none;
}

select.form-control + .chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 34px;
  padding: 6px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: #555;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
  transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
  background-image:none;
}

select.form-control + .chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices li.search-field input[type="text"] {
  height:auto;
  padding:5px 0;
}

select.form-control + .chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices li.search-choice {

  background-image: none;
  padding: 3px 24px 3px 5px;
  margin: 0 6px 0 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-color: #CCC;
}

select.form-control + .chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices li.search-choice .search-choice-close {
  top:8px;
  right:6px;
}

select.form-control + .chosen-container-multi.chosen-container-active .chosen-choices,
select.form-control + .chosen-container.chosen-container-single.chosen-container-active .chosen-single,
select.form-control + .chosen-container .chosen-search input[type=text]:focus{
  border-color: #66AFE9;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075),0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075),0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
}

select.form-control + .chosen-container-multi .chosen-results li.result-selected{
  display: list-item;
  color: #ccc;
  cursor: default;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.1.0/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.1.0/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<select class="form-control chosen" data-placeholder="Choose an option please">         
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1" >Option 1</option>
  <option value="2" >Option 2</option>
</select>
```